# textbox does not active by clicking on radio button

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

i have created two radio button to get value i.ee max it goes to same varibale total. i wanted to active only one textbox at a time. and accept value.

```
<dt>
            <dd>
        <input id="clicking"  data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton"  name="method" type="radio" value="clickarea" checked="false">
        <label for="clicking">By Clicking</label><br>
                   <input type="text" name="Name" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
                   data-dojo-props="trim:true, propercase:true" value="" id="Area1" disabled = "true" >
            </dd>
        </dt>
       <br></br>
       <dt>
           <dd>
       <input id="draw"  data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton" name="method" type="radio" value="drawarea" >
        <label for="draw">Draw Area</label><br>
         <input type="text" name="Name" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
                   data-dojo-props="trim:true, propercase:true" value="" id="Area2" disabled = "true"">
            </dd>
         </dt>


if (document.getElementById('clicking').checked) {
    document.getElementById('Area1').disabled = false;
    var container = dijit.byId("Area1");
    container.set("value", evt.graphic.attributes.Area_);
    area = container;
} else {
    document.getElementById('Area1').disabled = true;
}
if (document.getElementById('draw').checked) {
    document.getElementById('Area2').disabled = false;
    area = e.values;
    document.getElementById("Area2").value = area.toFixed(2);
} else {
    document.getElementById('Area2').disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: any suggestion? i do not get it why it does not work.

Comment: kindly guide me what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: added an answer.. is that helpful ?

Comment: do u have any idea how to create external file like js file or css file for modals. means i have created a modal in html body now i want to create a separate file for the modal.

Comment: modal means bescially html popup? you want to create a separate modal file and want to reuse this.. correct ? let me check...

Comment: yes correct , i want create separate file   for modal like we create css file and js file

Comment: got any idea how to do this?

Comment: yup.. I can suggest you to create custom widget for modal. and use that widget as a new class. below are two different and easy way to create widget.. using dojo or jquery... https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/recipes/custom_widget/ ...... https://jqueryui.com/widget/ ....... this way u will create modal once and reuse everywhere... let me know if you need this in detail..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there were some syntax error.

Check below working code-

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/esri/css/esri.css">

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/">
    </script>
    
    <script>
    function enableDisableTextArea(){
if (document.getElementById('clicking').checked) {
    document.getElementById('Area1').disabled = false;
    var container = dijit.byId("Area1");
    //container.set("value", evt.graphic.attributes.Area_); // get this value first
    area = container;
} else {
    document.getElementById('Area1').disabled = true;
}
if (document.getElementById('draw').checked) {
    document.getElementById('Area2').disabled = false;
   // area = e.values; //need to get this value first
    //document.getElementById("Area2").value = area.toFixed(2);
} else {
    document.getElementById('Area2').disabled = true;
}
 
 }
    </script>
<dt>
            <dd>
        <input id="clicking"  data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton"  name="method" type="radio" value="clickarea" checked="false" onClick ="enableDisableTextArea()">
        <label for="clicking">By Clicking</label><br>
                   <input type="text" name="Name" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
                   data-dojo-props="trim:true, propercase:true" value="" id="Area1"  >
            </dd>
        </dt>
       <br></br>
       <dt>
           <dd>
       <input id="draw"  data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton" name="method" type="radio" value="drawarea" onClick ="enableDisableTextArea()">
        <label for="draw">Draw Area</label><br>
         <input type="text" name="Name" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
                   data-dojo-props="trim:true, propercase:true" value="" id="Area2" disabled = "true"">
            </dd>
         </dt>
```

**Updated JSFiddle-** https://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/f2hxt25d/6/

Hoping this will help you :)

Comment: kindly look at this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253486/alert-box-does-not-close?noredirect=1#comment75515409_44253486

Comment: kindly look at this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430855/custom-map-does-not-display/44446762#44446762 ang give me suggestion how to do this

Comment: Ok let me check