# prompt keeps coming up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have calculation form i want to put empty validation check on each textbox. but the problem is alert box does not close after checking first box.i want to check 10 fields before calculation button click.

```
function checkTextField(field) {
   if (field.value == 0) {
       window.prompt(field.name + "cannot be empty");
       field.focus();
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}   


<input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="txt1" name = "Rate " onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" onblur = "checkTextField(this)" autofocus/>
<input class="form-control" id="txt2" name="1" type="number" required onblur = "checkTextField(this)" >
```

Comment: Blur -> Event Handler -> Prompt -> Focus -> Blur ... and the cycle continues. Commenting `field.focus()` will work.

Comment: Additionally, you've now found out why `alert()` can be evil since they block the UI. A better approach would be to have a message appear in a DOM element next to the field. This won't block the UI. ... And, don't use in line HTML event handling attributes (`onclick`, `onmouseover`, etc.). Use dedicated JavaScript with `.addEventListener()`.

Comment: @Rohan Kumar This isn't the kind of code that should be in a snippet.

Comment: @ScottMarcus i think i would b better if u help me out rather than commenting what is wrong and right

Comment: @SarahSalar I was typing my answer during that time. Please be patient as we are all here to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a vicious cycle of events that lead back to each other, so every time you clear your `propmt`, a new one is generated. Whenever  the user leaves a field and you detect that it is invalid, you set the focus back to it, causing whatever field the user just moved to to lose its focus, causing another validation error.

Additionally, you've now found out why `alert()` and `prompt()` can be evil since they block the UI.

A better approach would be to have a message appear in a DOM element next to the field. This won't block the UI.

... And, don't use in line HTML event handling attributes (`onclick`, `onmouseover`, etc.). Use dedicated JavaScript with `.addEventListener()`. **[Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)**.

```js
// Place this code in a <script> element, just before </body>

// Get references to any HTML elements you'll need to work with
var txt1 = document.getElementById("txt1");
var txt2 = document.getElementById("txt2");

// Set up event handling functions here, not in the HTML
txt1.addEventListener("blur", validate);
txt1.addEventListener("input", validate);
txt2.addEventListener("blur", validate);
txt2.addEventListener("input", validate);

// This one function is called when either field is having input entered 
// or when the user leaves either field.
function validate(evt) {
  // All event handling functions are automatically passed a reference to the
  // event that they are handling (evt here). From that object, we can get a 
  // reference to the object that triggered the event (evt.target here).
  // Lastly, always call the .trim() string method on user input. It strips
  // any leading or trailing spaces off of the inputted value (a common user mistake).
  var val = evt.target.value.trim();
  
  var message = ""; // This will hold any error message we wish to show
  
  // Begin validations
  if(val === ""){
    message = "Can't be empty!";
  } else if(isNaN(parseInt(val,10))){
    message = "Not a number!"
  }
  
  // Place the error message in the element that comes just after the invalid field
  evt.target.nextElementSibling.textContent = message
}
```

```css
span.error { color:red; }
```

```html
<!-- Note the empty span elements just after each field... -->
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="Rate" autofocus><span class="error"></span>
<input type="number" id="txt2" name="1" required><span class="error"></span>
```